# Remove dots ( ... ) from default search results descriptions ( snippet )

Tags: theming, search

I want to remove dots from search results items descriptions to search result page ( Default Search ), i have used Drupal default search for the search result page so how to remove the dots from the search descriptions.

I tried with search and replace function using theme preprocess search result function but no luck.

> theme_preprocess_search_result()

[image]

```
function theme_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {

  $variables['search_excerpt'] = str_replace("...", "", $variables['snippet']['#markup']);

}
```

But it's not work as expected,if have any solution please put into comment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use incorrect variable name.

Take a look for the [search-result.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21templates%21search-result.html.twig/8.8.x) template.
We have a snippet template variable.

Your code should looks like:

```
function theme_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  $variables['snippet']['#markup'] = str_replace('…', '', $variables['snippet']['#markup']);
}
```

Pay attention to …, this is a special symbol, not ... (three dots).

Comment: Thanks @ivan Tibezh.. It is working now.